# No such partitions grub rescue>

Tags: unity, boot

I installed ubuntu 12.10 on my desktop, to try it out.. it worked fine. now i wanted to install windows 7, inserted win 7 dvd formatted all the partitions,its not successfully installed. now when i tried to boot it shows " No such partitions grub rescue> " error. help me to install windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You should start a boot fix process in windows 7 installation repair section

1- On first screen of boot on windows 7 click repair

2- Start a auto repair process , it most of the times find correct windows installation and works ok , but if it failed to repair it go to step 3

3- Open a recovery console and run

```
[drive letter]:\fixboot
[drive letter]:\fixmbr
[drive letter]:\Bootcfg /rebuild
```

it should correct the problem.